# Change value field using Classes

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript, lotus

I am learning the classes in lotusscript and I have found this issue that I don't know how to solve.

I have a class where it read a field, and depending of the value of this field the method of the class have to change to other. The method is `Status`

**Code Class**

```
%REM
    Library c_LlamadaCandente
    Created 28-nov-2016 by David Bernabe Palanco/ES/HPH
    Description: Comments for Library
%END REM
Option Public
Option Declare


%REM
    Class c_LlamadaCandente
    Description: Comments for Class
%END REM
Class LlamadaCandente

    ' Declare the parameters
    Private m_datStart As Variant
    Private m_datFinal As Variant
    Private m_strClaim As String
    Private m_strGroupClaim As String
    Private m_strStatus As String

    ' Constructor
    Public Sub New (dateStart, group, status)
        me.m_datStart = dateStart
        me.m_strGroupClaim = group
        me.m_strStatus = status
    End Sub

    ' Calculate the person who has to answer the form
    Public Function Responsable As String
        Dim group As String

        group = me.m_strGroupClaim

        Select Case group
        Case "Autos 1"
            Responsable = "user 1"
        Case "Autos 2"
            Responsable = "user 2"
        Case "Particulares 1"
            Responsable = "user 3"
        Case "Particulares 2"
            Responsable = "user 4"
        Case "Empresas 1"
            Responsable = "user 5"
        Case "Empresas 2"
            Responsable = "user 6"
        Case "Personales"
            Responsable = "user 7"
        Case "Lesiones"
            Responsable = "user 8"
        Case Else
            Responsable = "user 9"
        End Select
    End Function

    ' Change the status field
    Public Function Status As String        

        Select Case me.m_strStatus
        Case "Borrador"
            Status = "Pendiente"
        Case "Pendiente"
            Status = "Finalizado"
        Case Else
            Status = "Sin estado"
        End Select

    End Function

End Class
```

**Form**

Into the form I have a field called `Estado` with the initial value "Borrador", and a buttom with this code

**Buttom Code**

```
Sub Click(Source As Button)

    ' We create new object from Llamadas Candentes and then we instanciate it with the parametres
    Dim llamada As New LlamadaCandente(doc.FechaSolicitud(0), doc.LlcGrupo(0), doc.Estado(0))

    llamada.Status

    Call uidoc.Save
    Call uidoc.Close

End Sub
```

**The issue**

When I call `llamada.Status` I really hope to change the `doc.Estado`, but it doesn't work. So when i have done click into the buttom the new value of the field will have "Pendiente", but the form when it is closed has the value "Borrador", as the beginning.

Any suggest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The NotesDocument object has methods for changing its values. You are changing the properties on the LlamadaCandente object but you want to change the values on the document object.

One simple solution is to add this in your click handler:

```
doc.ReplaceItemValue("Status", llamada.Status)
```

or

```
uidoc.FieldSetText("Status", llamada.Status)
```

Comment: thanks a lot. I have use `doc.Estado = llamada.Status` because with `.ReplaceItemValue` and `.FieldSetText` i have an error with the illegal parentheses.

Comment: You have the illegal parentheses error when you don't use the Call command. There are two ways: _doc.ReplaceItemValue "Status", llamada.Status_ or _Call doc.ReplaceItemValue("Status", llamada.Status)_

Comment: Or you could use `doc.Estado = llamada.Status()`, or you could change `Public Function Status As String' to 'Public Property Get Status As String' and then you can use `doc.Estado = llamada.Status` because then it's treated like a property, not a function.

Comment: The idea is that if you are getting the values from a function inline, you (almost?) always have to use a *function(arg1, arg2)* syntax, such as `x = lamada.Status()`  However, if you are using a sub or using a function in a way where you don't care about the return variable, then you can use either a *Call functionOrSub(arg1, arg2)* syntax or a *functionOrSub arg1, arg2* syntax.